# Swing & NetBeans 6.7.2 design view

Tags: swing, netbeans

I could not open the swing java file in design view because *.java and *.form are in different folder. How can I link those files in Netbeans ?

Comment: Ref : What is form file ?

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormFormFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6.7 there is no way to store the .form and .java files separately.